# \cite{keyword} just outputs "keyword" in bold

Tags: biblatex

A latex file that I have is set up like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref}

\begin{document}
\cite{keyword}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When I compile this, I get an output of **keyword** and nothing else. The biblatex file is in the same folder as the latex file, I am copying the keyword straight from the .bib file into latex, and I have tried including the .bib tag so it is `\addbibresource{ref.bib}`. The bib file has been exported from Zotero using BetterBibTex under the export option "BetterBibLaTeX." I feel like I have all my bases covered, so I am curious why this is not working.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: have you tried to run biber or bibtex command ?

Comment: Assuming your `.bib` file is called `ref.bib` the correct call is `\addbibresource{ref.bib}`. `\addbibresource{ref}` is incorrect and not guaranteed to work. You will need to run Biber on your document. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. If you usually have your editor compile your file for you read https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: What editor are you using to compile your file?

Comment: Any news here? As your question stands now it is hard to say what exactly your problem is. The missing file extension is definitely something that should be fixed, but the fact that Biber is not mentioned in the question makes me think the much bigger issue here is that your editor/workflow is not configured to run Biber.